# Downloading data osm2pgsql

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

I uploaded a large *.osm file. Now from it you need to import into the postgis data having amenity = parking in my table. Import only polygons. Polygons must be imported into the "polygon" field. All other fields in the table will be populated with default values. Tell me, can this be done with osm2pgsql

Comment: Hey there. Just to make sure I got it right: You want to import into PostGIS only the polygons from your osm file, right?

Comment: Only polygons with amenity = parking

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/62404/downloading-data-osm2pgsql

Comment: If you're not willing to write an script to do so, consider importing this file into `QGIS` and then importing your subset into `PostGIS`.